# create self-extract auto installer winzip on linux to run on windows

Tags: windows, linux, self-extracting

i have created an installer using nsis and a data file included, i m trying to create a self auto extractor containing both of those files via linux so that they would run on windows(exe).

is that possible?

Comment: I'm of mixed feeling about the vote to migrate to Super User. Certainly it is a request for a tool, but is a deployment tool not *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: i realy have dificulties understanding your issue i m a asking for development advice or other code/tool that could assist me resolving my problem

Comment: I don't know if you can see a *"close (1)"* below your post, but for people with enough rep it is there. It means that someone ([with at least 3000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)) has voted to move this question to Super User (and this will take effect if 4 more people agree). I was expressing my opinion that this might not be correct (i.e. that the question should stay here).